How can I solve invalid remote certificate in Blazor App?
I have a Blazor Server App that makes calls to a REST API from a server. I have the problem that when I make a call to that server, I get the following error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be
established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate
chain: NotTimeValid

I have tried to disable SSL validation like this:
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
    {
        return true;
    };

    http = new HttpClient(handler);

And executing these commands that some people suggest:
   dotnet dev-certs https --clean
   dotnet dev-certs https --trust

But nothing has worked. Anyone knows how I could solve it?
